# How can I have a shared schema in multi tenancy architecture with spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, multi-tenant

After several readings about multi tenancy and how to implement it. I finally got my application working using Spring boot 2, Jpa and hibernate.

What I have for now is a schema per tenant architecture and every request use an X-tenantID header key to define the tenant from which the data should be queried.

Once I tried to implement security I found myself limited by this header key. What I want to achieve is to have a shared tenant where I should store all my users with the tenant identifier for each one of them, along with some other informations that should be used from all tenants. If it's possible how can I achieve such behavior? Is there a github project reference ? If a solution like eclipselink is proposed can you please reference an article explaining it's integration with spring boot?

The second question is how to create at runtime a new schema in database once a use is registered? A sample code or a documentation reference should be very welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: @AjitSoman For now I'm using two profiles: H2 for development and PostgreSQL for production.

Comment: Are you using spring data jpa and hibernate in project

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using for now

Comment: @AjitSoman Using mySQL database with your response from the other post it did work, but this is because MySQL doesn't make a difference between a database and a schema. I'm digging on how to make it work with PostgreSQL and H2 :/

Comment: Since you are implementing `Schema per tenant` , You are creating separate database in a physical database. For PostgreSQL you just have to change connection parameters. Did you got any exception while implementing with PostgreSQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168142/discussion-between-habchi-and-ajit-soman).